# Can Oracle 12c execute a vbscript?

Tags: oracle

Is there a way for an Oracle 12c stored procedure to execute a VB Script? MS SQL can do this using xp_cmdshell - is there an equivalent in Oracle?

Comment: not like how you want, but you could write a java stored procedure to make any OS based command you want on the server

Comment: Any links to how to make Java stored procedures?

Comment: Oracle Docs, but I found a couple of good posts on AskTom, here's one https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:952229840241#2717585194628